# FTP - command or setting to set "never overwrite" for a whole session

Tags: delphi, ftp, synchronization, ararat-synapse

I'm using Ararat Synapse for Delphi, so if there's a way to set such a mode (or get ls results to a stringlist) I can do it with code. I've looked at the unit code and the dokuwiki and haven't found anything conclusive.

But if there's an FTP command or setting I could use to prevent overwrites (resulting in a GET or PUT not being performed) it would save me a lot of time.

The only way using normal FTP commands that I see right now is to put each file in a folder. Before creating the folder I try to CD to it and PWD the current directory.

In other words, a sort of "sync folders", but only for a specific list of file names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such FTP command for what you are asking.  You have to implement such logic in your own code.  If a file already exists in the destination folder, simply don't issue a `GET` or `PUT` command.  Use Delphi's FileExists() function to check if a local file exists.  Use the FTP `LIST`, `MLST`, and/or `SIZE` command(s) to check if a remote file exists.

Comment: I followed your advice and LISTed out existing files for a correct sync of those not on the list. This is now part of a pretty complex system that has been running well for months at our customer's. Thanks!